# Showing a pop up in Shiny when downloading tweets

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following functions stored in a file called "functions_S.R"

```
connect_twittR_api <- function() {

  library(twitteR)

  consumer_key <- my_key
  consumer_secret <- my_secret_key
  access_token <-  my_access_token
  access_secret <-  my_access_token

  setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_secret)

}
```

And the function

```
scrape_tweets <- function(){

  N=10  # tweets to request from each query
  S=200  # radius in miles

  lats=c(38.9,40.7, 37.8)
  lons=c(-77,-74, -122)
  cities=c("Alabama","Alaska", "Arizona")

  donald_temp <- searchTwitter('Donald+Trump',
                               lang="en",n=N,resultType="recent",

  geocode=paste(lats[1],lons[1],paste0(S,"mi"),sep=","))
  print(paste0("Scraping tweets for: ", cities[1]))

  df_total <- create_dataset(donald_temp, cities[1])

  for(i in 2:length(lons)){

    print(paste0("Scraping tweets for: ", cities[i]))
    donald_temp <- searchTwitter('Donald+Trump',
                            lang="en",n=N,resultType="recent",
                            geocode=paste(lats[i],lons[i],paste0(S,"mi"),sep=","))

    df_temp <- create_dataset(donald_temp, cities[i])
    df_total <- rbind(df_total, df_temp)
  }

return(df_total)
}
```

So runnning:

```
connect_twittR_apI()
scrape_tweets()
```

Gives me a list of tweets from Donald Trump from the states:"Alabama","Alaska", "Arizona". This is all works, however I would like to include it in a Shiny application - to be triggered by a button.

So the skeleton looks like this:

```
library(shiny)
setwd("")
source("functions_S.R")


UI <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("button", "An action button")
)
Server <- function(input, output) {

  observeEvent(input$button, {
    connect_twittR_api()
    tweets <- scrape_tweets()
  })

}


shinyApp(ui = UI, server = Server)
```

Now the the paste elements from the function:

```
 print(paste0("Scraping tweets for: ", cities[1]))
```

Run on the background. I would like to to have a pop-up screen showing a progress bar the paste message. Any thoughts on how I should implement this?

Comment: You could open a modal using` bsmodal()` from the shinybs package.